# Template argument deduction from an element in nested braces

Tags: c++

I want to make a function that returns a random element from a list, weighted. The type of the elements should be deduced.

Choosing a random element is easy, but I can't figure out how to conveniently pass the list into the function.

For example, `choose({{0.5, "foo"}, {0.25, "bar"}, {0.25, "baz"}});` should deduce the element type as `const char *` and return one of the three strings.

I tried this:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
T choose(std::initializer_list<std::pair<double, T>> list)
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    choose({{0.5, "foo"}, {0.25, "bar"}, {0.25, "baz"}});
}
```

But it doesn't compile:

```
<source>:11:5: error: no matching function for call to 'choose'
<source>:4:3: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
```

I know I can make it work using

```
choose({std::pair{0.5, "foo"}, std::pair{0.25, "bar"}, std::pair{0.25, "baz"}});
```

, but I'd prefer a more terse syntax.

I could make a variadic template, invocable without any braces (`choose(0.5, "foo", 0.25, "bar", 0.25, "baz")`), but without pair separators it becomes hard to read if the element type is also `double`.

Comment: In fact, [only one `pair` is enough](https://godbolt.org/z/G1v9W88cM) to deduce the type, but it may still be verbose for you...

Comment: @康桓瑋 That looks better, but I wonder if it's possible without that `pair`.